# Порядковая статистика в дереве

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Я мучаюсь с реализацией дерамиды и поиском порядковой статистики и ранга элемента в ней. Дерамиду я балансирую при помощи поворотов дерева. Как мне помнится, сама дерамида уже строилась правильно, а возникают проблемы, видимо, с полями size, которые необходимы для нахождения порядковой статистики. В консольном выводе видно, что они заполняются совершенно неправильно! Программа вылетает на процедуре os_select. Как все это можно исправить?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


typedef struct node{
public:
    int key;
    int priority;
    int size;
    node *left;
    node *right;
    node *parent;

    node(int k);
} node;

node::node(int k){
    key = k;
    priority = rand() % 701;
    size = 1;
    left = right = parent = NULL;
}

/*Возвращает указатель на узел, содержащий i-й в порядке
 *возрастания ключ в поддереве с корнем root*/
struct node * os_select(struct node *root, int i){
    int r;
    if (root != NULL && root->left)
        r = root->left->size + 1;
    else
        r = 1;
    if(i == r) return root;
    else{
        if(i < r) return os_select(root->left, i);
        else      return os_select(root->right, i - r);
    }
}

/*По заданному указателю на узел x дерева с корнем root
 *возвращает позицию данного узла при центрированном обходе*/
int os_rank(struct node *root, struct node *x){
    int r = x->left->size + 1;
    struct node *y = x;

    while(y != root){
        if(y == y->parent->right)
            r = r + y->parent->left->size + 1;
        y = y->parent;
    }
    return r;
}

void traversal(node *root, int level) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        traversal(root->left, level+1);
        for (int i =0; i< level; ++i)
            printf("--");
        printf("%d %d %d\n", root->key, root->priority, root->size);
        traversal(root->right, level+1);
    }
}

void left_rotate(node **root, node *x) { // NOTE: node **root
    node *y = x->right;
    x->right = y->left;
    if (y->left != NULL) y->left->parent = x;
    y->parent = x->parent;
    if (x->parent == NULL) *root = y; // NOTE: корень может помен¤тьс¤!
    else {
        if (x == x->parent->left)   x->parent->left = y;
        else                        x->parent->right = y;
    }
    y->left = x;
    x->parent = y;
    // Пересчет полей size после поворота
    y->size = x->size;
    x->size = 1;
    if (x->left)
        x->size += x->left->size;
    if (x->right)
        x->size += x->right->size;
}

void right_rotate(node **root, node *x) { // NOTE: node **root
    node *y = x->left;
    x->left = y->right;
    if (y->right != NULL) y->right->parent = x;
    y->parent = x->parent;
    if (x->parent == NULL) *root = y; // NOTE: корень может поменяться!
    else {
        if (x == x->parent->right)  x->parent->right = y;
        else                        x->parent->left = y;
    }
    y->right = x;
    x->parent = y;
    // Пересчет полей size после поворота
    y->size = x->size;
    x->size = 1;
    if (x->left)
        x->size += x->left->size;
    if (x->right)
        x->size += x->right->size;
}

void insert(node **root, node *z) { // NOTE: node **root
    node *x = *root;    //отмечает проходимый путь
    node *y = NULL; //ссылается на родительский по отношению к x узел
    node *p = NULL;

    while (x != NULL) {
        y = x;
        if (z->key < x->key) x = x->left;
        else                 x = x->right;
    }
    z->parent = y;
    if (y == NULL) *root = z; // NOTE: корень может поменяться!
    else {
        if (z->key < y->key) y->left = z;
        else                 y->right = z;
    }
    z->size = 1;
    x = z;  //Для прохода вверх
    while (x != *root && x->priority > x->parent->priority) {
        if (x == x->parent->left)
            right_rotate(root, x->parent);
        else /* x == x->parent->right */
            left_rotate(root, x->parent);
    }
}


#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v;
    srand(time(NULL));

    node *tree = NULL, *p, *nth;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        p = new node(i*11 % 17);
        insert(&tree, p);
    }
    traversal(tree,0);
    nth = os_select(tree, 10);
    std::cout << "nth element:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << nth->key << std::endl;


    int pause = 0;
    std::cin >> pause;
}
```

Результат работы: https://ideone.com/FRaWjF

Оказалось, что никакого результата на идеоне не получилось. Дерево выводится только у меня в консоли.

Comment: дерамида (или декартово дерево) балансируется за счет приоритетов. Балансировка поворотами применяется к другим видам деревьев. Как лушче писать дерамиду можно найти здесь: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/treap

Comment: Я знаю, что такое дерамида=) Но мне также сказали, что и на поворотах МОЖНА ЗДЕЛОТЬ.

Comment: И повороты там как раз вызываются так, чтобы сортировать элементы по приоритетам.